# How to put a break on an instruction specified by address in gdb?

Tags: assembly, gdb

How can I put a break point to that instruction. When I write either:

```
break 9048f23
break *9048f23
```

It does not work.

How I can put a break point to that instruction.

```
9048f23:    8a 51 e6                mov    0x12(%esp),%eax
```

Platform: Linux.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You just need to add the hex prefix:

```
b *0x9048f23
```

Answer (score 3):

By default, you'll need the `0x` prefix to specify a hex number (as Igor says; +1).

If you prefer hex to be used for numeric input in general (without needing a prefix), you can change the default with:

```
set input-radix 16
```

You can also change the default output radix with `set output-radix`, or both at the same time with `set radix`; see the [relevant section of the `gdb` documentation](http://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Numbers.html) for details.

(And you can put these commands in your `~/.gdbinit` file if you want them to apply automatically to every `gdb` session.)